# Update field with new string made from characters in existing value

Tags: mysql, update

field is `meta_value` and current value is like `01/01/2006`

i want to change it to a string `20060101` so thought i could get the value and update it with the characters in the correct order.

ie

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = meta_value[9]meta_value[8]meta_value[7]meta_value[6]
```

Comment: Please state RDBMS. String manipulation functions are not well standardised.

Comment: Also tell us if you have 20th of Jan stored as `20/01/2006` or `01/20/2006`.

Comment: Hello - 'current value is like 01/01/2006' & what is RDBMS?!

Comment: @danielCrabbe - He is asking which database are you using,  Mysql, Postgresql, etc.

Comment: @danielCrabbe - Also telling us current value is like `01/01/2006` doesn't help us deduce if that is `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy`

Comment: sorry! SQL - and current format is Eu so dd/mm/yyyy. Thanks...

Comment: What dialect of SQL? MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, ...?

Comment: Wordpress means (99%) mysql.

Comment: Yes mysql. First post here. Will be better in future. Dc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that meta_value is **always** dd/mm/yyyy and you are looking for yyyymmdd (which isn't clear), try this:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET meta_value = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(meta_value FROM 7), 
     SUBSTRING(meta_value, 4, 2), 
     SUBSTRING(meta_value, 1, 2));
```

Run that as a SELECT first to verifying the output before update and make sure it's what you're really looking for.

Comment: ok - ran this Select CONCAT(SUBSTRING(meta_value FROM 7), SUBSTRING(meta_value, 4, 2),  SUBSTRING(meta_value, 1, 2)) FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'end_date' and all looks great. That is going to come in v handy. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As the field is stored as `varchar(255)` in that table (that is, it's stored as a string, rather than a special date format), you'll need to slice it and then join the chunks together.

Assuming that the original date is dd/mm/YYYY and the required format is YYYYmmdd then you could do something like this:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = concat(substring(meta_value,7,4),substring(meta_value,4,2),substring(meta_value,1,2))
```

This is using the `substring` function to split the original string, the format of this command is:

```
substring(string to split,starting position in string, length of required substring)
```

This isn't the only format, more examples are here - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr

Then we use the `concat` function to join the 3 new strings as one (details on that one here - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

But you'll need to be very careful running that update as it is. At the moment it will do that for **every** row in the table. So if you have a row with post_meta='Stuart Moore' it will be updated to 'MooarSt' which probably isn't what you want. So make sure you use a where clause to restrict which rows you're modifying.

Answer (score 3):

If `meta_value` field type is a DATE then you could use

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET meta_value = DATE_FORMAT(meta_value, '%Y%m%d');
```

or if it is a string then use

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET meta_value = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(meta_value, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y%m%d');
```

[More on MySQL date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)